# How to combine two tables with "count" inside

Tags: mysql, sql, combinations

Need your help, How would I join two tables below? each of them has "count" function.

table 1:

```
SELECT page,   count(page)
FROM table 1
WHERE date = '2016-04-04'
GROUP BY page
```

output (table 1):

```
page | count(page) |
231  |           1 |
232  |           2 |
233  |           3 |
```

table 2:

```
SELECT page,   count(page)
FROM table 2
WHERE date = '2016-04-04'
GROUP BY page
```

output (table 2):

```
page | count(page) |
231  |           4 |
232  |           5 |
233  |           6 |
```

what I want to achieve is like this:

```
page | count(page) | page1  |  count(page1)  |
231  |           1 |     231|             4  |
232  |           2 |     232|             5  |
233  |           3 |     233|             6  |
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do something this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "Files" FROM files WHERE Folder = n;
```

It's called a correlated subquery.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html[1](http://%3Chttp://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html%3E)

Answer (score 0):

An INNER JOIN between those two result tables would do the job done.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
SELECT 
page,   
count(page) countOfTable1
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2016-04-04'
GROUP BY page) firstTable

INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
page,   
count(page) countOfTable2
FROM table2
WHERE date = '2016-04-04'
GROUP BY page ) secondTable
ON firstTable.page = secondTable.page ;
```

Comment: It's a good practice to mark answer as **accepted** which works for you so that others can find it useful. @user3928201

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.page AS 'page',
       t1.count AS 'count(page)',
       t2.page AS 'page1',
       t2.count AS 'count(page1)'
FROM table_1 AS t1,
     table_2 AS t2
WHERE t1.page=t2.page
```